# IGMP: Host rejecting igmp query from src "0.0.0.0"

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, igmp

As per RFC4541, it is valid scenario for a proxy to send IGMP query with src as 0.0.0.0.
Also, the RFC says, section 2.1.1 (4) that "If the switch is not the Querier, it should use the 'all-zeros' IP Source Address in these proxy queries (even though some hosts may elect to not process queries with a 0.0.0.0 IP Source Address).

The question is : how to make host to accept these queries instead ? Is there is a switch or would it need a patch on Linux/debian buster 4.19.99

Answer (score 0):

Found that it's fixed in kernel 5.1+

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/net/ipv4?id=1d2f4ebbbeb1ec055dcd3cf3dba833cfd0a84f3a